# office.js ExecuteFunction take long time to invoke after the first invoke

Tags: excel, office-js

We are building an Excel Web Add-in using `office.js`.

We have a button on a custom tab with that triggers an `ExecuteFunction` action.

We noticed the function that is invoked works fine the first time but subsequent clicks take 3-4 minutes to invoke.

Does anyone experience the same issue? Any help on this would be appreciated.

*We've also noticed the `Refresh All Connections` on Data tab also behaves the same way. Not sure if this is an larger issue with Excel Online.*

Comment: we noticed the `Refresh All Connections` on `Data` tab also behaves the same way.. not sure if this is an issue with excel online application.

Comment: You mention Excel Online, have you also seen this behavior on the desktop? Or is this only happening with Excel Online?

Comment: It is happing only with excel online. In excel desktop it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Long time posted, no answer. Well, I think you have to call `event.completed();` at the end of your function. Otherwise Excel Online will not know you're done. It will then wait for the `event timeout`, thus the long time to run after the first try.I had the same problem with my first add-in, which added a button to the ribbon to perform a minor task on a cell. The code structure should be like this:

`function myFunction(event) {
    Excel.run(function (context) { return context.sync(); })["catch"](function (error) { });
    event.completed(); // This will do the magic.
}`